# Dependency issue while installing perl-Net-SNMP

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel6

When I tried installing `perl-Net-SNMP`, I get the dependency error below :

```
# yum install perl-Net-SNMP

...

--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC) for package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-4.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::SHA1) for package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-4.el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-4.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(Digest::HMAC)
Error: Package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-4.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(Digest::SHA1)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows your yum server do not have all dependencies for  **perl-Net-SNMP** that's why this showing dependency resolution error when you are installing perl-Net-SNMP first you need to install these dependency's manually from another repository after complition of dependency resolution/installtion you need to run this commond **yum install perl-Net-SNMP**

you can get this dependency's from pkgs.org,rpm.pbone.net and other repositories.

Comment: you can download this rpm from these repositories using wget on terminal than install by rpm -ivh rpmname .

Comment: It's installed perfectly, thank you !                    http://pastebin.com/MrjC8npn

Answer (score 0):

Install the needed perl packages by running:

```
cpan -i Digest::HMAC
cpan -i Digest::SHA1
```

After which run `yum install perl-Net-SNMP` again

Comment: I still have the same problem : http://pastebin.com/UVJ2Pyj2

Comment: Try installing perl-Net-SNMP also using cpan like: cpan -i Net::SNMP

Comment: Is it installed now ? http://pastebin.com/zRVjDnx3

Comment: Yes from what I see. You need also to check with a perl script by including this package there though.

Comment: `# perldoc -l Net::SNMP`
`/usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SNMP.pm`
Thank you !